# Executing canoe testmodule with Com interface in python throws an error

Tags: python-3.x, com, pywin32, canoe

```
#`Execute XML Test Cases without a pass verdict"""
import sys
from time import sleep
import win32com.client as win32

CANoe = win32.DispatchWithEvents("CANoe.Application")
CANoe.Open("canoe.cfg")

test_env = CANoe.Configuration.TestSetup.TestEnvironments.Item('Test Environment')

# Cast required since test_env is originally of type <ITestEnvironment>
test_env = win32.CastTo(test_env, "ITestEnvironment2")
# Get the XML TestModule (type <TSTestModule>) in the test setup
test_module = test_env.TestModules.Item('AutomationTestSeq')

# {.Sequence} property returns a collection of <TestCases> or <TestGroup>
# or <TestSequenceItem> which is more generic
seq = test_module.Sequence
for i in range(1, seq.Count+1):
    # Cast from <ITestSequenceItem> to <ITestCase> to access {.Verdict}
    # and the {.Enabled} property
    tc = win32.CastTo(seq.Item(i), "ITestCase")
    if tc.Verdict != 1: # Verdict 1 is pass
        tc.Enabled = True
        print(f"Enabling Test Case {tc.Ident} with verdict {tc.Verdict}")
    else:
        tc.Enabled = False
        print(f"Disabling Test Case {tc.Ident} since it has already passed")
```

I tried running above code but the step tc.verdict!=1 throws an error as pywin32 error :member not found.
any leads on how to fix this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a test group then a test case object in your `.xml` file or at least that's how it worked for me. first I had a test case object which includes CAPL test function and I couldn't access the verdict even when casting `ITestSequenceItem` to `ITestCase`, but when tried to put the test case inside test group then cast it from `ITestSequenceItem` to `ITestGroup`  then to `ITestCase` it worked... if possible could you provide more info about your XML file structure for the test cases ? I believe its an object hierarchy issue